# Error while trying angularjs with rails:undefined method `register_engine' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am new to both angularjs and rails.
In my new company we have to use ruby on rails with angularjs. After takingup tutorials for angularjs and ruby on rails separately, I was trying how the both would work together using the following link:
   https://thinkster.io/angular-rails#generating-activerecord-models 
After following all steps till the topic "Integrating the Front-end with the Asset Pipeline" (including steps in this topic) when I run rails s command the following error comes:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.5 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
**/home/cb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@flapper-news/gems/angular-rails-templates-0.1.4/lib/angular-rails-templates/engine.rb:49:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>': undefined method `register_engine' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)**
    from /home/cb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@flapper-news/gems/angular-rails-templates-0.1.4/lib/angular-rails-templates/engine.rb:39:in `each'
    from /home/cb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@flapper-news/gems/angular-rails-templates-0.1.4/lib/angular-rails-templates/engine.rb:39:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /home/cb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@flapper-news/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/cb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@flapper-news/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /home/cb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@flapper-news/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /home/cb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /home/cb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/cb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/cb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/cb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
    from /home/cb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
    from /home/cb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/cb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
    from /home/cb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
    from /home/cb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@flapper-news/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /home/cb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@flapper-news/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
    from /home/cb/flapper-news/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/cb/flapper-news/config.ru:3:in `require'
    from /home/cb/flapper-news/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /home/cb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@flapper-news/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/cb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@flapper-news/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from /home/cb/flapper-news/config.ru:in `new'
    from /home/cb/flapper-news/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /home/cb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@flapper-news/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /home/cb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@flapper-news/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /home/cb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@flapper-news/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /home/cb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@flapper-news/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /home/cb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@flapper-news/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
    from /home/cb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@flapper-news/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
    from /home/cb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@flapper-news/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
    from /home/cb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@flapper-news/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:139:in `log_to_stdout'
    from /home/cb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@flapper-news/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:78:in `start'
    from /home/cb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@flapper-news/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
    from /home/cb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@flapper-news/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from /home/cb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@flapper-news/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from /home/cb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@flapper-news/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /home/cb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@flapper-news/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/cb/flapper-news/bin/rails:9:in `require'
    from /home/cb/flapper-news/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/cb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@flapper-news/gems/spring-1.6.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    from /home/cb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@flapper-news/gems/spring-1.6.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    from /home/cb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@flapper-news/gems/spring-1.6.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /home/cb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@flapper-news/gems/spring-1.6.0/lib/spring/client.rb:28:in `run'
    from /home/cb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@flapper-news/gems/spring-1.6.0/bin/spring:51:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/cb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@flapper-news/gems/spring-1.6.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    from /home/cb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@flapper-news/gems/spring-1.6.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/cb/flapper-news/bin/spring:13:in `require'
    from /home/cb/flapper-news/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Using rails version 4.2.5

Following is a snippet of the Gemfile:

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'

    gem 'angular-rails-templates'

    gem 'rails', '4.2.5'

    gem 'sqlite3'

    gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'

    gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

    gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'

    gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc


    group :development, :test do

      gem 'byebug'

    end

group :development do

gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

gem 'spring'

end
```

Comment: If the answer solved you problem you should accept it, if not you can ask for more help. @Ashi

Comment: @marcpt none of the suggestions worked. I deleted all and started the steps again and it worked. Seems I had followed any step incorrectly or missed. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 14):

I had the same issue. It was a problem related with 'sprockets'. Try to install an older version adding `gem 'sprockets', '2.12.3'` to your gem file and then update your gems by running `bundle update`.
It worked for me.

Comment: 2.12.4 also fixed the issue for me, but none of the following: 3.0.3, 3.1.0, 3.2.0, 3.3.5, 3.4.1. 3.5.2. By the way, I'm not using AngularJS.

Comment: Why did it relate to `sockets`?

Comment: @NewAlexandria it's `sprockets` not `sockets`

Comment: Thx @JoãoDaniel.  Same question

Comment: @NewAlexandria AngularJS gems are basically assets gems with JS files and `sprockets` is a rack-based assets manager. It's a version compatibility issue that's already reported on the gem's repository. :)